# ActiveRecord converts symbol keys to strings when serializing my hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, yaml

I have a Rails model class with a serialized Hash attribute, like this:

```
class Action
  serialize :metadata, Hash
  # . . .
end
```

That column is stored in a `text` column with a YAML encoding. The problem is that when I pass a `metadata` value to the `create!` method, the hash keys are converted from symbols to strings, but that conversion doesn't happen other times. For example:

```
$ rails console
> a = Action.create!(:metadata => {:foo => "bar"})
> a.metadata
 => {"foo"=>"bar"}
> a.metadata[:fizz] = "buzz"
> a.metadata
 => {"foo"=>"bar", :fizz=>"buzz"}
```

Now when I save the model, the database is going to have this text value:

```
---
foo: bar
:fizz: buzz
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

(This is with Rails 3.0.16.)

Comment: Does it exhibit the same behavior with `serialize :metadata, HashWithIndifferentAccess`?

Comment: @gregates: I tried it, and it means I can query the hash with either strings or symbols and get the value, but there are two problems: `Action.create!(:metadata => {:foo => :bar})` raises an exception because I'm not allowed to pass a plain Hash anymore, and `Action.find(an_old_id)` raises a SerializationTypeMismatch exception because Rails doesn't know how to convert the YAML into a HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to answer this myself, with a variant of @Mori's suggestion:

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  def metadata=(v)
    self[:metadata] = v.try(:symbolize_keys!)
  end
end
```

As far as I can tell, this works around the problem without breaking the interface elsewhere. I guess if I *wanted* a key to be a string, this method would cause me a nasty surprise, but that's not the case, so I'm more willing to accept it than the surprises raised by other proposed solutions.

Btw, if someone can propose a solution that doesn't require this sort of workaround at all, I'll happily accept that as the correct answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  def metadata
    self[:metadata].try :symbolize_keys
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, but now if I say `a.metadata[:foo] = 'bar'` the change is lost, because I'm assigning to a copy of the hash, not the hash referenced by the model.

Comment: . . . But, it *does* work if I instead say `self[:metadata].try :symbolize_keys!`. That feels sort of wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going another route.  I make sure I get a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` back when I access the attribute:

```
def metadata
  return self[:metadata] if self[:metadata].is_a?(HashWithIndifferentAccess)
  self[:metadata] = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(self[:metadata])
end
```

An added bonus to this is if `metadata` isn't set I get an empty hash back instead of `nil`